# How to solve differential equation $f'(x) = f(x) - f(x-1) $ with $f(0)= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the ODE:

$f'(x) = f(x) - f(x-1)$ where $f(0)= 0$, and $x \geq 0$

Note: I am trying to solve a problem where it came up and I haven't done DE for years and thus not sure where to start.

Comment: I don't think that this would be considered an *ordinary* differential equation, in ODEs the function itself as well as the derivatives are all evaluated at the same point.

Comment: This is not an ODE, but a *delay differential equation*.

Comment: corrected the question

Comment: One solution is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: One solution is $f(x) = constant$. The other solution can be found by considering $f(x) = exp(C*x)$.

Comment: I am interested in the solution of the form $f(x) = exp(Cx)$ since I am trying to solve this problem: 
You are given black-box which returns a random number between 0 and 1(uniform distribution).You keep generating random numbers X1,X2,X3 and so on and store the sum of all those random numbers. You stop as soon as the sum exceeds 1.What is the expected number of random variables used in the process?

I formulated this problem as the above differential equation. Now, if I show $exp(x)$ satisfies the condition at $x=0$ and the differential equation, is that enough?

Comment: No, that is not enough. Because the overall solution is $f(x) = A + B * exp(C*x)$, where $C$ follows from substution into the original equation. The parameters $A$ and $B$ are free, and determined by the boundary conditions.

Comment: Yes. $B=-A$ and $C$ is a constant which we can express in terms of [W Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: $C$ turns out to be $0$. Not terribly interesting.

Comment: We can define $f$ pretty freely on $[-1,0]$ and compute $f$ on $[0,1]$ via integration, then $[1,2]$, and so on. That is, there are many possible solutions.

Comment: @robjohn, not sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @hi15: I was going to use the example of $f(x)=x$ on $[-1,0]$, but that turns out to be a solution for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So let's try $f(x)=-x^2$ on $[-1,0]$. Then we need to solve $f(x)-f'(x)=-(x-1)^2$ which leads to the solution of $-x^2-1+e^x$ on $[0,1]$, which then leads to the solution of $-x^2+(2-x)e^{x-1}+e^x-2$ on $[1,2]$, etc.

Comment: Actually, $f(x)=cx$ is a solution for any $c$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why we can't take laplace transform, get $\mathcal{L}(f)(s)=0$ for all $s$ big, and then obtain $f=0$?